# PHP retornando json como string

Tags: php, javascript, json, api

Estou retornando esse *JSON* utilizando *PHP* mas o objeto `genre` e `cast` esta sendo retornado como *string*

```
{  
   "id":"5",
   "title":"A Era do Gelo",
   "year":"2002",
   "age":"0",
   "time":"81",
   "genre":"[{\"id\": 16, \"name\": \"Anima\u00e7\u00e3o\"}, {\"id\": 35, \"name\": \"Com\u00e9dia\"}, {\"id\": 10751, \"name\": \"Fam\u00edlia\"}, {\"id\": 12, \"name\": \"Aventura\"}]",
   "cast":"[{\"name\": \"Ray Romano\", \"image\": \"https:\/\/images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com\/images\/M\/MV5BMTM4NzA4ODQxNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwMDA5Mjk1._UY317_CR16,0,214,317_AL_.jpg\", \"imdb_id\": \"nm0005380\", \"character\": \"Manfred       (voice)\"}, {\"name\": \"John Leguizamo\", \"image\": \"https:\/\/images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com\/images\/M\/MV5BNTEyMjMxNDg5NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNzczOTY4MQ@@._V1_UY44_CR2,0,32,44_AL_.jpg\", \"imdb_id\": \"nm0000491\", \"character\": \"Sid       (voice)\"}, {\"name\": \"Denis Leary\", \"image\": \"https:\/\/images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com\/images\/M\/MV5BMTk2MzM4NTA5OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMTAxNjA3Mg@@._UY317_CR16,0,214,317_AL_.jpg\", \"imdb_id\": \"nm0001459\", \"character\": \"Diego       (voice)\"}, {\"name\": \"Goran Visnjic\", \"image\": \"https:\/\/images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com\/images\/M\/MV5BNDk1ODI0Nzc0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzQzNDczNw@@._UY317_CR16,0,214,317_AL_.jpg\", \"imdb_id\": \"nm0899681\", \"character\": \"Soto       (voice)\"}, {\"name\": \"Jack Black\", \"image\": \"https:\/\/images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com\/images\/M\/MV5BMjE2MjI4NTQxN15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDMyMDg4NTE@._V1_UY44_CR1,0,32,44_AL_.jpg\", \"imdb_id\": \"nm0085312\", \"character\": \"Zeke       (voice)\"}, {\"name\": \"Cedric the Entertainer\", \"image\": \"https:\/\/images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com\/images\/M\/MV5BMTcxODQ1NTU5NV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjMwMjY0NA@@._V1_UY44_CR0,0,32,44_AL_.jpg\", \"imdb_id\": \"nm0147825\", \"character\": \"Carl       (voice)\"}, {\"name\": \"Stephen Root\", \"image\": \"https:\/\/images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com\/images\/M\/MV5BMTQ3MDA3OTA5OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjQ4MDU0NA@@._UY317_CR16,0,214,317_AL_.jpg\", \"imdb_id\": \"nm0740535\", \"character\": \"Frank \/              Start       (voice)\"}, {\"name\": \"Diedrich Bader\", \"image\": \"https:\/\/images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com\/images\/M\/MV5BMTkzMTkyNzYyOV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNTMyNDE0._V1_UY44_CR0,0,32,44_AL_.jpg\", \"imdb_id\": \"nm0046033\", \"character\": \"Oscar       (voice)\"}, {\"name\": \"Alan Tudyk\", \"image\": \"https:\/\/images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com\/images\/M\/MV5BMjE0MzEwNDUxNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTE1MDAzOQ@@._UY317_CR16,0,214,317_AL_.jpg\", \"imdb_id\": \"nm0876138\", \"character\": \"Lenny \/              Oscar \/              Dab       (voice)\"}, {\"name\": \"Lorri Bagley\", \"image\": \"https:\/\/images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com\/images\/M\/MV5BMTc1OTAyODk1Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwMjM2MDQz._UY317_CR16,0,214,317_AL_.jpg\", \"imdb_id\": \"nm0046715\", \"character\": \"Jennifer       (voice)\"}, {\"name\": \"Jane Krakowski\", \"image\": \"https:\/\/images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com\/images\/M\/MV5BMjIyMTQ5NTI1Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNTU2MDY2NzE@._V1_UY44_CR6,0,32,44_AL_.jpg\", \"imdb_id\": \"nm0005105\", \"character\": \"Rachel       (voice)\"}, {\"name\": \"Peter Ackerman\", \"image\": \"\", \"imdb_id\": \"nm0010004\", \"character\": \"Dodo \/              Macrauchenia       (voice)\"}, {\"name\": \"P.J. Benjamin\", \"image\": \"\", \"imdb_id\": \"nm0071344\", \"character\": \"Dodo       (voice)\"}, {\"name\": \"Josh Hamilton\", \"image\": \"https:\/\/images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com\/images\/M\/MV5BMTU1ODA3MzE1MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODMxMzg1MQ@@._V1_UY44_CR0,0,32,44_AL_.jpg\", \"imdb_id\": \"nm0357979\", \"character\": \"Dodo \/              Aardvark       (voice)\"}, {\"name\": \"Chris Wedge\", \"image\": \"https:\/\/images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com\/images\/M\/MV5BMTQ3OTE5MjcxNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMTE0MTU0MjE@._V1_UY44_CR0,0,32,44_AL_.jpg\", \"imdb_id\": \"nm0917188\", \"character\": \"Dodo \/              Scrat       (voice)\"}]",
   "director":"Pessoa",
   "description":"O mamute Manny (Ray Romano\/Diogo Vilela), o tigre de dente de sabre Diego (Dennis Leary\/M\u00e1rcio Garcia) e a pregui\u00e7a-gigante Sid (John Leguizamo\/Tadeu Melo) s\u00e3o amigos em uma \u00e9poca muito distante dos dias atuais e vivem suas vidas em meio a muito gelo. At\u00e9 o dia em que eles encontram um menino esquim\u00f3 totalmente sozinho, longe de seus pais, e decidem que precisam ajud\u00e1-lo a achar a sua fam\u00edlia. Enquanto isso, o esquilo pr\u00e9-hist\u00f3rico Scrat segue na sua saga para manter sua amada noz protegida de outros predadores.",
   "source":"http:filme..mll",
   "principalThumb":"\/thumbs\/87be74a3ae83a909d9a54ad354307cfc6566162.jpg",
   "type":"movie",
   "token":"d34c-4638-de1a-bc19-066b-5630-8699-d4c5-9d98-35bc"
}
```

Codigo PHP:

```
  function showContents($tb, $token = 0){
    // Busca um conteudo no bd de acordo com o token
    if ($token) {
        $showContents = $this->pdo->connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tb WHERE token=:token");
        $showContents->bindParam(":token", $token, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $showContents->execute();
        if ($showContents->rowCount() == 1){
            return $showContents->fetchObject();
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }else{
        // Busca todos os conteudos da tabela no bd
        $showContents = $this->pdo->connect()->query("SELECT * FROM $tb");
        return $showContents->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }

}
```

Minha tabela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: qual é o codigo que esta gerando isso?

Comment: Editei a pergunta

Comment: Genre e Cast também é um JSON, pelo que parece. Não basta usar json_decode para torná-lo um array?

Comment: Do jeito que ele está sendo mostrado, eu não consigo exibir os dados com javascript

Comment: Por causa dos escapes das aspas?

Comment: Sim............

Comment: Para mim, as imagens são bloqueadas onde estou, mas respondi, acredito que sejam strings no BD, por isso elas chegam pra você como string, e não um array de objetos.

Answer (score 0):

Eles estão retornando como strings porque no Banco de Dados acredito que eles sejam strings, e a função `fetchObject/fetchAll` não fazem a conversão automaticamente da coluna para objeto (não que eu saiba rs).

Você tem 2 opções, fazer a conversão após o fetchObject, ou usar uma classe que o construtor faça isso de forma transparente pra você.

### Opção 1 - Após o fetchObject

```
function showContents($tb, $token = 0) {
  // Busca um conteudo no bd de acordo com o token
  if ($token) {
    $showContents = $this->pdo->connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tb WHERE token=:token");
    $showContents->bindParam(":token", $token, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $showContents->execute();
    if ($showContents->rowCount() == 1) {
      $obj = $showContents->fetchObject();
      $obj->genre = json_decode($obj->genre);
      $obj->cast  = json_decode($obj->cast );
      return $obj;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    // Busca todos os conteudos da tabela no bd
    $showContents = $this->pdo->connect()->query("SELECT * FROM $tb");
    $objs = $showContents->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    foreach($objs as &$obj) {
      $obj = $showContents->fetchObject();
      $obj->genre = json_decode($obj->genre);
      $obj->cast  = json_decode($obj->cast );
    }
    unset($obj);
    return $objs;
  }
}
```

### Opção 2 - Usando uma classe

```
class Filme {
  public $id;
  public $title;
  public $year;
  public $age;
  public $time;
  public $genre;
  public $cast;
  public $director;
  public $description;
  public $source;
  public $principalThumb;
  public $type;
  public $token;

  // construtor é chamado depois das propriedades serem preenchidas pelo fetchObject e fetchAll, por isso funciona
  function __construct() {
     $this->genre = json_decode($this->genre);
     $this->cast  = json_decode($this->cast );
  }

}

function showContents($tb, $token = 0, $class_name = "stdClass") {
  // Busca um conteudo no bd de acordo com o token
  if ($token) {
    $showContents = $this->pdo->connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tb WHERE token=:token");
    $showContents->bindParam(":token", $token, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $showContents->execute();
    if ($showContents->rowCount() == 1) {
      $obj = $showContents->fetchObject($class_name);
      return $obj;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    // Busca todos os conteudos da tabela no bd
    $showContents = $this->pdo->connect()->query("SELECT * FROM $tb");
    $objs = $showContents->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ, $class_name);
    unset($obj);
    return $objs;
  }
}

// e na hora de chamar a função, passe o nome da classe
$filme10 = showContents('TBL_FILMES', 10, 'Filme');
```

### Mais informações

- [fetchObject](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchobject.php)
- [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchall.php)